# Service to send mail from my webapp

Tags: java, email

I am running a webapp on Apache Tomcat. I want my app to send out an email to the users, for certain actions. I have tried using Java Mail, but I am not happy with performance.

I would like to use an external service for the same. I came across MailChimp, but realized, it doesn't suit my requirements, as I want to send the mail IMMEDIATELY, rather than later, as a part of a campaign. I want something that will let me send a mail to an id, IMMEDIATELY.

Can anyone here, suggest any service, for this? Any reviews/past experiences? Will be very appreciated.

Cheers,
RD

Edit :
Thanks all for the suggestions. But I don't want to continue with my code for sending out emails. I have noticed issues with my email id getting blocked, infrequent delays of upto 3 hours before delivery of email etc. I want to use a webservice, which helps me send out mails. That is what, my question is.

Solution :
Thanks to all the help from the people here, mostly to JonLim, I zeroed in on PostageApp and PostmarkApp. However, finally settled on Postmark, because they seemed to have an easier Java client! I blogged a post on how  I configured and integrated my webapp [here](http://thoughts.citynaksha.com/2011/07/sending-email-using-postmark.html).

Comment: Why you are not happy about performance of Java Mail?

Comment: Harry, I have edited my post above to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have plenty of email service providers at your disposal:

- [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com) (Ours!)
- [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com)
- [PostmarkApp](http://postmarkapp.com)
- [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)

Figure out which one suits your needs and take your pick!

(**Full Disclosure:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp.)

Comment: Thank You JonLim. This is what I was looking for. More updates, after I have successfully integrated with PostageApp (trying your product first)! :)

Comment: Definitely let me know if I can help you out and if you have any questions. Happy to help! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue with the java mail API is that it's not very developer-friendly. For that purpose there is [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/). As for performance - its performance is fine - it just creates a raw SMTP request to the SMTP server. So the problem must be either in your code or in your SMTP server.

Comment: Bozho, I have edited my post, to better explain my question/need.

Comment: this looks infrastructure-related, rather than coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you should find out the source of the slowness (profiling your application). That will help determine how to improve it.

That being said, you should definitely take a look at your MTA configuration. I use postfix and it's fast, secure, and easy to configure and maintain.

Comment: Moe, I have edited my post, to better explain my question/need.